# How do I compile and link a library (SDL) with g++ so that I have a standalone program?

Tags: c++, compilation, sdl

I'm using MinGW on Windows 7.

Put simply, I want to create a Hello World SDL program (initiate a window or something simple), and compile it so that I have a standalone program that I can distribute without, say, users having to install anything extra (like putting `SDL.dll` in the Windows folder).

- I've downloaded the SDL development library, which is currently
  sitting in `c:\SDL`.
- In my project folder I've got `test.cpp` and `SDL.dll`

I'm not too sure what to do next; I thought at first I would be able to include SDL and then just link to the DLL in the commandline and voila, but perhaps it would seem I need to compile the SDL development library with my program first? My only goal is to have my SDL program wrapped up in a folder that I can distribute to other Windows platforms without the requirement that they have to install anything extra - or would they definitely need to install SDL.dll in the Windows folder?

EDIT: Further clarification - could someone describe the steps that I'd take to do this? I mean, what would a developer looking to distribute his application do? Do most game installers actually put `.dll` files in the `Windows` folder when applications like this are installed?

Source (test.cpp):

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

Folder:

`test.cpp`
`SDL.dll`

Commandline:

`g++ test.cpp -lSDL`

Output:

`test.cpp:2:17: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory`
`compilation terminated`

Comment: They would definitely need the SDL.dll but it doesn't have to be in the Windows folder. You can load it from anywhere if you wish. Look up the LoadLibrary Windows API. Might be an idea to do some research on 'DLL injection' since that seems to be a hot security topic at the moment.

Comment: Your compiler can't find the header file SDL/SDL.h, you probably need to use `g++ -IC:/SDL test.cpp -lSDL` or something (sorry I'm not sure how SDL installations look).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> include SDL and then just link to the DLL in the commandline and voila

Yes, pretty much that's it.

> but perhaps it would seem I need to compile the SDL development library with my program first?

What? Unless you're developing for an embedded system, there's no separate "development" library. You link against the very same DLL that will be loaded when your program is started.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate more on the actual process? I just need to compile via `g++` and link the DLL file in the command line options?

Comment: @DesmondWolf Yes, exactly. Pay attention to the include and library paths (you may need to specify them manually using `-I` and `-L`).

Comment: Thanks. In my source I've got `#include <SDL/SDL.h>` and `SDL.dll` is in the same folder as my code. But I'm not sure what commandline options to use to get this to compile. If I do: `g++ test.cpp -lSDL`, it says: `fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: Unfortunately, `-I.` doesn't seem to have any effect. I couldn't find it in `--help` or any documentation, but I assume the period is something to do with the current directory?

Comment: @DesmondWolf yes, right, and it should work if the `SDL` directory with the `SDL.h` file inside resides in the same directory from where you invoke the compiler command.

Comment: Thanks, I see now, needed to go all the way to the actual location of the .h files, e.g `g++ -Ic:\sdl\include\sdl -lSDL test.cpp`. Thanks.